# .NetCore Getting Video Metadata from IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm uploading video as blob to azure blob storage. Is there anyway to extract the video width and height from the IFormFile before uploading to the server?

This is my upload code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddVideo(int id, IFormFile video)
{   

if (video != null)
{
        if(video.Length > 0)
        {

            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            var uniqFileName = "video-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;

            var result = await _blobService.UploadFileBlobAsync(
                "video",
                file.OpenReadStream(),
                file.ContentType,
                uniqFileName
            );

            uploadedUrl = result.AbsoluteUri;


        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No,you could not get video metadata from IFormFile before uploading the server.There is  no such property in IFormFile to get the width and height.

Comment: So in order to get the width and height, i need to save file somewhere first?

Comment: Yes.You need to save it first.